# Apply image filter to HTML video in FabricJS

Tags: html, video, fabricjs

I managed to adapt the HTML 5 video example for FabricJS given at http://fabricjs.com/video-element to change the opacity of the video.

Then I thought, wouldn't it be cool to blur the video. So I messed around with that, but no luck.

I just added a line with a new grayscale below

```
var video1 = new fabric.Image(video1El, {
  left: 350,
  top: 300,
  angle: -15,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});
video1.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale());
```

but it does not work.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

For opacity, it's easy (variable : opacity) : http://jsfiddle.net/Da7SP/309/

For Grayscale, with canvas, it's possible

Like this : http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/

To Grayscale :

```
function draw(v,c,bc,w,h) {
    if(v.paused || v.ended) return false;
    // First, draw it into the backing canvas
    bc.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
    // Grab the pixel data from the backing canvas
    var idata = bc.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
    var data = idata.data;
    // Loop through the pixels, turning them grayscale
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=4) {
        var r = data[i];
        var g = data[i+1];
        var b = data[i+2];
        var brightness = (3*r+4*g+b)>>>3;
        data[i] = brightness;
        data[i+1] = brightness;
        data[i+2] = brightness;
    }
    idata.data = data;
    // Draw the pixels onto the visible canvas
    c.putImageData(idata,0,0);
    // Start over!
    setTimeout(function(){ draw(v,c,bc,w,h); }, 0);
}
```

I don't know if it's difficult to add this in fabricjs